# "That's what" or "that's all what"

Tags: grammaticality

I would like to know which sentence is more grammatical and understandable.

> That's what remains of a man just after a long babysitting day.

> That's all what remains of a man just after a long babysitting day.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start from what I am sure of : your second sentence is incorrect because you cannot use ***what*** after ***all***. If you want to use this sentence, you should alter it to

"That's ***all that*** remains of a man..."

The first sentence, on the other hand, is perfectly correct and understandable, so the choice between the two (your first one and the amended second one) is according to your preference.

If I were to write such sentences, however, I would alter the ending, modifying the word order thus :

"... after a long ***day babysitting***."

I can't tell you why, but the other turn of the sentence just doesn't sound correct to me. I may be wrong, though, and I'd like to have some confirmation of my feeling from a native speaker.

Comment: You're quite right. A *day babysitting* is a day spent in babysitting, which is clearly what is meant here; a *babysitting day* would be a day appointed for babysitting. ... I would add that *what's/that's **left*** is more colloquial than *what/that **remains***.

Comment: @StoneyB. Thank you for your explanation. I frequently have gut feelings about the way English works, but I'll never reach mother tongue competence. I also agree on *left* rather than *remains*, but I guess it escaped me because I was more concentrated on the other issue...

Comment: Thank you Paola. So, If I've perfectly understood, I'd better substitute the verb remain with the verb left. the new sentence would be 'That's left of a man just after a long day babysitting'.

Comment: @jeysmith. Not exactly. You can say either *"That's all that's left of a man (just) after a long day babysitting"* or *"That's what's left of a man (just) after a long day babysitting"*. In either case, I feel that *just* is unnecessary and perhaps even odd.